# Como obtengo el id por medio de linq asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Me encuentro aprendiendo a utilizar ASP, pero me surge el presente problema: Recibo  el valor `patente`, verifico que me regrese la primera patente de la tabla, pero no quiero almacenar nuevamente la patente, quiero almacenar el id que contiene a esa patente.

¿Cómo lo puedo resolver?

Este es el código:

```
public atencion Vehiculo GetIdAtencionVehiculo(string patente)
{
     atencionVehiculo idPatente= bd.atencionVehiculo.Where(c => c.PatenteVehiculo == patente).FirstOrDefault();
     return idPatente;
}
```

Estaré muy agradecido que me pudieran ayudar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var IďPatente = (from v in db.atencionVehiculo
                 where v.patenteVehiculo == patente
                 select v.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Hacemos la consulta Linq con la condición deseada en el **where** y en el **select** especificamos el campo a devolver que en este caso es el **ID**, posteriormente se invoca al **operador FirstOrDefault** que nos devuelve el primer elemento de la colección en caso de que no esté vacía, tu error estaba en que te faltó poner el **operador select**.

Además tu método debe devolver un **int**, actualmente estás devolviendo otro tipo de datos y la **variable Idpatente** también debe ser un **int**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Lo intento, pero se me subraya todo con rojo 

`public atencionVehiculo GetIdAtencionVehiculo(string patente)
        {
            atencionVehiculo IďPatente = (from v in bd.atencionVehiculo
                         where v.PatenteVehiculo == patente
                         select v.idNroAtencion).FirstOrDefault();
            return IďPatente;
        }`
Lo mismo me sucedía con la consulta anterior al ingresa un select

Comment: @LeonardoAntonioMolinasCarde ya arreglé, revisa

Comment: Seria public int getIdAtencionVehiculo....

Comment: Tu método debe devolver un int

Comment: Gracias por tu paciencia. Funciono!

Comment: Jeje, no hay de que @LeonardoAntonioMolinasCarde

Comment: Puedo hacerte una nueva pregunta, la cual complica un poco mas el grado de la anterior?

Comment: @LeonardoAntonioMolinasCarde pregunta

Comment: Tengo tres tablas, las cuales son dependientes entre ella por medio de claves foraneas atencionVehiculos, propietarioVehiculo y responsablePago. La tabla atencionVehiculo tiene la propiedad patente, en base a la patente yo obtengo idNroAtencion. idNroAtencion es clave foranea, la que almaceno en la tabla responsablePago como NroAtencionId y la tabla propietarioVehiculo  no almacena claves foraneas, pero su idPropietario es dependiente de la tabla atencionVehiculos. Ahi la almaceno como propietarioId. Deseo saber como borrar los datos en las tablas al momento de ingresar patente (en linq)

Comment: A ver, te propongo que hagas una nueva publicación con esta pregunta, y pongas lo que has intentado, @LeonardoAntonioMolinasCarde

Comment: Deja esta pregunta como está y haz una publicación con la pregunta nueva @LeonardoAntonioMolinasCarde

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415390/eliminar-en-cascada-con-linq-asp-net