# Eliminar en cascada con Linq asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, asp

Tengo tres tablas, las cuales son dependientes entre ella por medio de claves foraneas atencionVehiculos, propietarioVehiculo y responsablePago. La tabla atencionVehiculo tiene la propiedad patente, en base a la patente yo obtengo idNroAtencion. idNroAtencion es clave foranea, la que almaceno en la tabla responsablePago como NroAtencionId y la tabla propietarioVehiculo no almacena claves foraneas, pero su idPropietario es dependiente de la tabla atencionVehiculos. Ahí la almaceno como propietarioId. Deseo saber como borrar los datos en las tablas al momento de ingresar patente, desde la capa de negocio (en linq) .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que soy nuevo programando y el código lo intento hacer pero no puedo. Al momento de querer borrar solo una tabla de las tres me figura null el valor delete

```
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    //Retorna Responsable por id
    public ResponsablePago GetResponsablePago(int id)
    {
        ResponsablePago responsable = bd.ResponsablePago.Where(c => c.NroAtencionId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return responsable;
    }

    //Eliminar usuarios
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete)]
    public void deleteResponsable(string patente)
    {

        var idNumeroAtencion = (from v in bd.atencionVehiculo
                         where v.PatenteVehiculo == patente
                         select v.idNroAtencion).FirstOrDefault();
        var idResponsable = (from v in bd.ResponsablePago
                                where v.NroAtencionId == idNumeroAtencion
                                select v.idCliente).FirstOrDefault();
        
        ResponsablePago delete = this.GetResponsablePago(idResponsable);
        bd.ResponsablePago.Remove(delete);
        bd.SaveChanges();
    }


}
```

Esta es de la acción desde la capa de presentación

```
  protected void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        AnulacionClienteBL abl = new AnulacionClienteBL();
        abl.deleteResponsable(txtPatente.Text.Trim());
    }
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código link para revisarlo.

Comment: Hola, no soy yo es que el sitio tiene como política que el usuario ponga el código que ha intentado, edita la pregunta y pégalo ahi

Comment: Ahí he añadido el código.

Comment: Dame un time que tengo que hacer unas cosas por acá, ahorita te ayudo

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: estoy aki........

Comment: Bueno por lo q lei parece que resolviste

Comment: Pero no esta resuelto de forma optima, tienes un mejor metodo? @Japv

Comment: En mi caso particular, yo no eliminó en cascada, pues esto puede eliminar información necesaria para otros usuarios, más bien yo pregunto si ese registro existe en otra tabla y de existir no lo borro, en caso contrario lo borro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude programar un código funcional en comparación a lo poco que tenia en el anterior, aunque dudo que sea el optimo, pero elimina en cascada las tres tablas. En una próxima actualización modificare el orden con la intención de eliminar el ultimo ingreso. Si alguien pudiera simplificar mi código o aportar con que puede ser lo optimo se lo agradecería bastante

```html
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    //Retorna Responsable por id
    public ResponsablePago GetResponsablePago(int id)
    {
        ResponsablePago responsable = bd
            .ResponsablePago.Where(c => c
            .idCliente == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return responsable;
    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    //Retorna atencion por id
    public atencionVehiculo GetAtencionVehiculo(int id)
    {
        atencionVehiculo atencion = bd
            .atencionVehiculo
            .Where(c => c
            .idNroAtencion == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return atencion;
    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    //Retorna atencion por id
    public PropietarioVehiculo GetPropietario(int id)
    {
        PropietarioVehiculo propietario = bd
            .PropietarioVehiculo
            .Where(c => c.idPropietario == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return propietario;
    }

    //Eliminar usuarios
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete)]
    public void deleteResponsable(string patente)
    {

        //Recibe patente desde la capa de presentacion a la capa logica
        //con la patente busca coincidencias en la tabla atencionVehiculo propiedad PatenteVehiculo
        //si existe coincidencia con algun valor de la propiedad PatenteVehiculo 
        //Solicita el idNroAtencion que contiene la fila de patente 
        int idNumeroAtencion = bd
            .atencionVehiculo.Where(v => v
            .PatenteVehiculo == patente)
            .Select(v => v
            .idNroAtencion)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        //Recibe patente desde la capa de presentacion a la capa logica
        //con la patente busca coincidencias en la tabla atencionVehiculo propiedad PatenteVehiculo
        //si existe coincidencia con algun valor de la propiedad PatenteVehiculo 
        //Solicita el propietarioId que contiene la fila de patente 
        int idPropietario = bd
            .atencionVehiculo
            .Where(v => v
            .PatenteVehiculo == patente)
            .Select(v => v
            .propietarioId)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        //Recibe idNumeroAtencion desde linq anterior 
        //con el idNumeroAtencion busca coincidencias en la tabla ResponsablePago propiedad NroAtencionId
        //NroAtencionId es clave foranea de idNumeroAtencion de la tabla atencionVehiculo
        //si existe coincidencia con algun valor de la propiedad NroAtencionId
        //Solicita el idCliente que contiene la fila de NroAtencionId 
        int idResponsable = bd
            .ResponsablePago.Where(v => v
            .NroAtencionId == idNumeroAtencion)
            .Select(v => v
            .idCliente)
            .FirstOrDefault();

 

        ResponsablePago deleteResponsable = this.GetResponsablePago(idResponsable);
        atencionVehiculo deleteAtencion = this.GetAtencionVehiculo(idNumeroAtencion);
        PropietarioVehiculo deletePropietario = this.GetPropietario(idPropietario);
        bd.ResponsablePago.Remove(deleteResponsable);
        bd.atencionVehiculo.Remove(deleteAtencion);
        bd.SaveChanges();
    }


}
```